# Working with methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm pretty new to coding Java. Below are codes for a program that is supposed to use several methods to ask for a string, reverse the string, test for palindrome and output the result of the test. I'm trying to debug my many errors.

```
public static String getReverse(String Original) {

            String reverse = "";
            for (int i = original.length()-1; i>-1;i--) {
                reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);     
            }
            return reverse;
}
public static boolean isPalindrome(String original, String reverse) {
             if (original.equals(getString(original))) {
                 return true;
                }
             else {
                 return false;
                }

}


public static String promptForPalindrome(String original, Scanner Keyboard) 
{
                    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.print("Please enter a palindrome:");
                    String original = keyboard.nextLine();
                    boolean answer = isPalindrome(original,reverse);
                    while (answer == false) {
                        System.out.printf("Error: %s is not a palindrome. Please enter a palindrome.", original);
                        original = keyboard.nextLine();
                    }
                    return reverse
                    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
                    System.out.print(promptForPalindrome);
}
}
```

Comment: You could start by identifying what those errors are.

Comment: Chupee - where ya gone to?

Answer (score 1):

For a start in `main`

you are calling

```
System.out.print(promptForPalindrome);
```

but if you **look** at the method `promptForPalindrome` you will see that it takes the parameters `String original, Scanner Keyboard`

**BUT**

These parameters are not even used, so maybe just delete them and change the `main` code to be

```
System.out.print(promptForPalindrome ());
```

Consider reading a basic java tutorial as well.

**edit**

Similar problems exist for `isPalindrome` - I suggest you change to

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String original) {
         return original.equals(getReverse(original));
}
```

and call it in as

```
 boolean answer = isPalindrome(original);
```

But then your `answer` in

```
while (answer == false) {
```

will never change - so many bugs

Answer (score 0):

The method signatures for the isPalindrome needs to be changed to only accept 1 string argument because you don't have the reversed string when it is called. Also there is no reason to pass in a scanner object for the prompt method because you instantiate it in the method. Also I changed your .equals to .equalsIgnoreCase so you don't get messed up by capitals. Also you need to update your boolean after each loop.

```
public static String getReverse(String Original) {  
                String reverse = "";
                for (int i = original.length()-1; i>-1;i--) {
                    reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);     
                }
                return reverse;
    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String original) {
                 if (original.equalsIgnoreCase(getReverse(original))) {
                     return true;
                    }
                 else {
                     return false;
                    }

    }


    public static String promptForPalindrome() {
                        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.print("Please enter a palindrome:");
                        String original = keyboard.nextLine();
                        boolean answer = isPalindrome(original);
                        while (answer == false) {
                            System.out.printf("Error: %s is not a palindrome. Please enter a palindrome.", original);
                            original = keyboard.nextLine();
                            answer = isPalindrome(original);
                        }
                        return getReverse(original);
                        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        System.out.print(promptForPalindrome());
```

Hope this helps I may have made some typos so let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lot of errors. Check the below working code with comments in it.

```
public static String getReverse(String original) {
    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = original.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverse;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String original) { // Two args are not required
    // use equals if you need a case sensitive match
    if (original.equalsIgnoreCase(getReverse(original))) { // Call getReverse() to reverse the string
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static String promptForPalindrome() { // Arguments are not required
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a palindrome:");
    String original = null;
    boolean answer = false;
    do { // Use a do-while loop since you need to continue till it is success
        original = keyboard.nextLine();
        answer = isPalindrome(original);
        if (!answer) {
            System.out
                    .printf("Error: %s is not a palindrome. Please enter a palindrome.",
                            original);
        }
    } while (!answer);
    keyboard.close(); // Close the Scanner
    return original;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(promptForPalindrome());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all your help,
I was finally able to debug the code.

```
         package osu.cse1223;
         import java.util.Scanner;
         public class Homework08a {

      public static String getReverse(String original) {

    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = original.length()-1; i>-1;i--) {
        reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);     
    }
    return reverse;
}
public static boolean isPalindrome(String original) {
    if (original.equals(getReverse(original))) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}


public static String promptForPalindrome(String msg, Scanner keyboard) {

    System.out.print(msg);
    String userInput  = keyboard.nextLine();
    return userInput;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String msg ="Please enter a Palindrome";
    String userInput = promptForPalindrome(msg, keyboard);
    while (isPalindrome(userInput) == false) {
        userInput = promptForPalindrome(msg, keyboard);

    }
    System.out.printf("%s is a palindrome", userInput);
     }
   }
```